# Python list operation (append multiple lists)

Tags: python, list, io, append, delimited

I have a text file called `test.txt` which contains data in this format

```
....
a|b|c|d|e
a1|b2|c3|d4|e5
a3|b5|c2|d1|e3
....
```

I want to get the values of each column into lists: something like this

```
list1=[a,a1,a3]
list2=[b,b2,b5]
```

I managed to get this done by doing this:

```
list1,list2,list3,list4,list5 = ([] for i in range(5))

for line in open('test.txt','r'):
    temp=line.split('|')
    list1.append(temp[0])
    list2.append(temp[1])
    list3.append(temp[2])
    list4.append(temp[3])
    list5.append(temp[4].strip())
```

Is there shorter way to append the values to each list? I can only think of using 1 line for each list as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip()` is your friend here:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 = zip(
    *(line.strip().split('|') for line in open('test.txt')))
```

As an added bonus, you could also use this even if you didn't know how many columns there were - just assign it to a single variable instead, and you'd get a list, each item of which is the values for a column:

```
column_values = zip(*(line.strip().split('|') for line in open('test.txt')))
# column_values[0] is [a,a1,a3] ...
```

---

Let's step through this a little bit. First, we'll take a look at what happens with just the `zip()` bit:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 = zip(
    [0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3,4])
```

results in `list1 = [0,0,0]` and so on, because `zip()` takes the first element from each list and puts it in a list as the first element of the result.

---

Now, how do we get to `zip(a,b,c)` from a sequence `[a,b,c]`? Simple: we use the `*` positional argument expansion operator. `zip(*L)` is the same as `zip(L[0], L[1], ...)`.

---

Finally, how do we get the list of lists we need to pass in? We use a generator expression:

```
(line.strip().split('|') for line in open('test.txt'))
```

creates a generator that yields a list of the items in each line, one line at a time (and strips whitespace off the items). This is exactly what we need to feed to `zip()` to get the result we want.

Comment: very informative! Not trying to be pesky, i have a few more questions.(1) I need the ouput as lists and not tuples.Is there a short way to convert them back without affecting the order? (only way i know is `list(tuple)`) (2) Does this keep the '\n' character at the last column?Do i need to use strip.() to remove it?

Comment: @ChrisAung I already included `strip()` in the generator (stripping before splitting means you don't have to special case any of the columns). As far as converting them back - `list()` is the way to go; if you're using the `column_values` version you could just add this line: `column_values = [list(i) for i in column_values]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of lists:

```
table = [[] for i in range(5)]

with open('test.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        for index, value in enumerate(line.strip().split('|')):
            table[index].append(value)
```

So instead of having `list1`, `list2`, etc., you just access the cells by `table[0][0]`, `table[2][1]`, etc.

Comment: Looks like he wants the transpose of that.